# onClick to call interface method from MainActivity

Tags: java, android, interface

I need to perform onClick to call the onItemSelected listener method of another class.I don't know how to call that method in Image button onClick listener.So that it will move to HomeFirstFragment Class.

**ItmeSelectedListener**

```
public interface ItemSelectedListener {

    public void onItemSelected(final int position, final String content);
}
```

**LayoutActivity.java:**

```
public class LayoutActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

ImageButton btn_click;

  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_grid3);

        btn_click = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_click);

   }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.btn_click:


             break;
        }
    }

}
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnTabChangeListener,ItemSelectedListener {

 private TextView action_bar_hometext;


 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

 @Override
    public void onItemSelected(int position, String content)
    {

        if(position==0)
        {
            action_bar_hometext.setText(content);
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
            HomeFirstFragment newFragment = new HomeFirstFragment();
            ft.replace(R.id.realtabcontent, newFragment);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();
        }
     }
```

If I click the btn_click in LayoutActivity class,I need to perform onClick to call interface method from MainActivity.

Anyone can help me with this.Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You may create your own listener and add the block of code that you want to execute on click in your own listener.

Create your Interface like

```
Interface MyListener{
    public void myClickListener(String content);
}
```

Now implement this in your MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnTabChangeListener,ItemSelectedListener,MyListener {
    public void myClickListener(String content){
        action_bar_hometext.setText(content);
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
        HomeFirstFragment newFragment = new HomeFirstFragment();
        ft.replace(R.id.realtabcontent, newFragment);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: please check my question one more time.I need to call the listener in LayoutActivity.Something I tried so far like this.    `ItemSelectedListener list;     case R.id. btn_flight:
                list.onItemSelected(0, "Flight Details");
                break;`   but its not worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to register your `MainActivity` class in the `LayoutActivity` class, so that `LayoutActivity` class can invoke the interface's method.

Add this to your `LayoutActivity.java`:

```
private static ItemSelectedListener mListener = null;

public static void register(ItemSelectedListener listener){
    mListener = listener;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.btn_click:
            if(mListener!=null){
                // ADD THIS LINE
                mListener.onItemSelected(POS/*Your position*/, CONTENT/*Your content*/);
            }

         break;
    }
}
```

Now, in your `MainActivity` class, register it to the `LayoutActivity` class and  follows:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    LayoutActivity.register(this);
}
```

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: When I click the image button it wasn't working.But no error in runtime

Comment: Add appropriate logs. Your MainActivity may not have been created at all, so it won't register. Add log statements at all interface related parts. Also, more that getting it to work, I want you to understand how interfaces work and are to be used. :)

Comment: I don't want the logs. I want you to add more log statements and track down the problem. I have tested this code and it works.

Comment: if mListener is null is null that means you are running LayoutActivity before ever calling MainActivity..This code should work

Comment: @Richard I don't think your MainActivity even got created! Can you tell me the sequence of events that you are trying to achieve. Like how your app starts and what all it should do.

Comment: App starts in a sequence from Activity 1->activity 2->LayoutActivity3->MainActiivty