# Null pointer exception on image button click

Tags: android

I am getting a null pointer exception at runtime.I tried to call the interface method from another activity while click the image button.

I have mentioned the error line and posted the relevant code.

**Stacktrace:**

```
07-24 04:42:38.962    4414-4414/com.ms.ha E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.ms.ha.activity.GridActivity3.onClick(GridActivity3.java:62)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**LayoutActivity.java:**

```
public class LayoutActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

ImageButton btn_click;

 private static ItemSelectedListener mListener=null;

 public static void register(ItemSelectedListener listener){
    mListener = listener;
 }

  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_grid3);

        btn_click = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_click);

        btn_click.setOnClickListener(this);
   }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.btn_click:


             if(mListener!=null){

                mListener.onItemSelected(0, "Home Details");

            }else{
                mListener.onItemSelected(1, "List Details");  --->62nd line

            }
             break;
        }
    }

}
```

**ItemSelectedListener**

```
public interface ItemSelectedListener {

    public void onItemSelected(final int position, final String content);
}
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnTabChangeListener,ItemSelectedListener {

 private TextView action_bar_hometext;


 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

 @Override
    public void onItemSelected(int position, String content)
    {

        if(position==0)
        {
            action_bar_hometext.setText(content);
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
            HomeFirstFragment newFragment = new HomeFirstFragment();
            ft.replace(R.id.realtabcontent, newFragment);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();
        }
     }
```

If I click the btn_click in LayoutActivity class,I need to perform onClick to call interface method from MainActivity.But unfortunately I got an error at runtime.

I dont know how to solve this one.Anyone can help me with this.Thank you.

Comment: you do not call register for your listener

Comment: show the code of `GridActivity3`

Comment: sorry gridactivity3=layoutactivity @AnandSingh.I cant edit my own post because it leads to submitting error.

Comment: I just answered this question. Please do not post a new question again. You should edit the previous post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31602233/onclick-to-call-interface-method-from-mainactivity/31603062?noredirect=1#comment51158433_31603062

Comment: I voted to close because same question again. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31602233/onclick-to-call-interface-method-from-mainactivity

Comment: @AnandSingh do as your wish.This one for error related question

Comment: Actually your `mListener` value is `null` that's why you are getting error in 62 line.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(mListener!=null){
       mListener.onItemSelected(0, "Home Details");
}else{
       mListener.onItemSelected(1, "List Details");  --->62nd line
}
```

if your listener not null you call some method on it otherwise you also trying to call some method on a null reference